# Removing link ID element from jQuery tabbed search script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery tabbed search script that gets content from a PHP file defined by the link and parses it to the results div element. The ID for each link is used to pull content from the correct file however type_ is needed in the link ID for the tabs to work which then doesn't pull content from the right place. How can I resolve this issue?

This is my current jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^=type_]").click(function(){
        type=$(this).attr("id");
        $("[id^=type_]").removeClass("selected");
        $("#"+type).addClass("selected");
        return false;
    });
    $("#type_tab1").click();
    $("#query").keyup(function(){
            var query=$(this).val();
            var yt_url=''+type+'.php?q='+query;
            if(query==''){
                  window.location.hash='';
                  document.title='My Search Script';
            }
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:yt_url,
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(results){
                   $('#results').html(results);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul> 
<li><a id="type_tab1" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab1</a></li> 
<li><a id="type_tab2" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab2</a></li> 
<li><a id="type_tab3" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to use only the part after the underscore character when you send your GET request.

If that's the case, you can do this in your click event hander:

```
type=$(this).attr("id").replace("type_", "");
```

Note that you can simplify this, because you don't need to use jQuery to get the `id` attribute:

```
type=this.id.replace("type_", "");
```